# Communicate between 3 nodeMCU

Tags: nodemcu

How should I verify the communication between three node MCUs where one behaves as server and the other two as clients such that data of each node mcu is obtained on all three?

Comment: you would verify the communication by transmitting pre determined data ... if the data arrives correctly, then the communication is working correctly ... if the data is incorrect, then the communication has an issue

Answer (score 0):

communication between 3 nodemcu can be done instead don`t assume one nodemcu as server other two as client. Mqtt is a message protocol which is used to transfer messages. Connect all the three nodemcu`s in the same network and host a mqtt server separately in the same network. Mqtt has to flexibility to send data from one nodemcu to other nodemcus which are in the same network. Publish and subscribe method can be used to get data or post data.

Go through this link

http://mqtt.org/

Comment: i want to communicate using the IPs of the nodemcu and not by the mqtt protocol.